# VBScript equals problems

Tags: vbscript, equals

I have been working on a vbs login and signup program I have a fully functional working signup program but I am having troubles seeing if a inputbox a.k.a the password is equal to the logged password from signup in a file

```
    uname = inputbox("Please type your Username.")
    pword = inputbox("Please ebter your Password.")

    Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(uname + ".txt",1)
    strFileText = objFileToRead.ReadLine()
    objFileToRead.Close
    Set objFileToRead = Nothing
    If strFileToRead = pword Then
        document.write("Welcome!")
              CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "forums.htm"
    Else 
    msgbox("Incorrect Username or Password")
    Wscript.Quit
    End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Use "Option Explicit". Then blunders like

```
strFileText = objFileToRead.ReadLine()
```

vs.

```
If strFileToRead = pword Then
```

(**strFileText <> strFileToRead**)

will be caught.